# Models of computation less powerful than DFA

Tags: finite-automata, computation-models

I wonder if there are "standard" models of computation that are less powerful than DFA that are still "mathematically interesting"? It is evident that restricting the set of DFAs in various conceivable ways easily yields examples, but would any of those generate considerably interesting mathematical questions?

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in [branching programs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NC_%28complexity%29#Barrington%27s_theorem), e.g., branching programs of bounded width (say, width 3, or width 5) and bounded length (say, linear length).

You might be interested in [probabilistically checkable proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistically_checkable_proof), where we focus on proofs that can be checked by a very limited form of computation -- namely, a randomized program that only looks at a constant number of bits of the proof.  That is an extremely limited model of computation, which leads to some challenging mathematics/theory.